# XMPPRoster example for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I have looked at the sample code and still not able to figure out some key functionality of the framework without more in depth documentation.  Normally there are books about frameworks but it seems like with this framework, you're on your own until it picks up more mainstream usage.

How do I get the roster list?  I see that XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage has an NSMutableSet of rosterPopulationSet. Is this the set of XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObjects, i.e., users, that make up a roster?

My way I'm guessing is a hack--get the presence of every user as it's announced, and stash it in an array. Those are the online buddies. Somehow get the entire roster list, and everyone who is not online, is offline.

I figure that there should be an array of XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObjects, i.e., 30 contacts, 30 entries in the XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObjects table?
How would I access this array and how would I tell if they are online or not?
For online status, am I supposed to query something else, b/c it's not encapsulated in XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObjects is it?
I suppose I could use the didReceivePresence or similar methods, but all in all, I want to use the framework and not fight against it.

Appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a basic understanding of how to retrieve the users roster? How to store that roster, array, dictionary etc.? Do you have a basic understanding of CoreData and how to store values?

Comment: I know the basics of CoreData.  I do not know where the roster is located in the framework or how to retrieve it.  Is it XMPPRoster, XMPPRosterCoreDataStorageObject, or XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.

Answer (score 4):

Use *XMPPRoster* extension with either *XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage* or *XMPPRosterMemoryStorage*

Take a look at following code. Please note that this is not complete code but should give you an idea.

```
XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:rosterstorage];  
[xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoster fetchRoster];
```

Comment: Thanks. I for some reason understand the in-memory roster storage better.  I can see that the roster is stored in an NSMutableDictionary after the call to [xmppRoster fetchRoster]. However, using CoreData, the corresponding structure should be:   NSMutableSet *rosterPopulationSet inside XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.

Comment: I haven't used XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage but as per my understanding it will handle storing data to db and you will have to use fetchedResultsController to access it.

Comment: @Nilesh would you please help me that after calling [xmpproster fetchRoaster], in which delegate methods it called to show the details of roster